# How to use 2 camera preview in surfaceView Android

Tags: android, android-camera

Recently I am trying to make a simple OCR app that reads numbers from a image.
And I want to use 2 preview in the camera to take the image in android like the link below.

[image]

Is it possible to use two surfaceView to take the image in android or are there any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like two camera previews. That looks like one camera preview with a couple of rectangles and some text drawn on it. Unless I'm missing something, you should be able to use a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), or a second SurfaceView with [setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay(boolean)) set, to render on top of the camera preview surface.

Comment: Thank you for the comment!  The thing that I dont understand about the app in the image above, is that the numbers within those 2 blue rectangles are scanned.  Since I'm a total noob, I want to know if there are a easier example for  setZOrderMediaOverlay(true).